# Sending a post request from postman returns status code 415

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, mediatr

I am using MediatR and Entity Framework Core and I have a post controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> RegisterUser(RegisterUserCommand request)
{
    var response = await _mediator.Send(request);
    if (!response.IsSuccess)
    {
        return BadRequest(response.Error);
    }

    return Ok(response.Result);
}
```

Where `RegisterUserCommand` is defined as

```
public class RegisterUserCommand : IPreprocessedRequest<ICommandResult>
{
    public string Email { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [ValidateNever]
    public string? Error { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to send a POST request from Postman it gives me a 415 error.

If it is necessary I can post the handler class

Comment: Status Code 415 -  Unsupported Media Type. So I suggest you recheck how you are sending your raw request.

Comment: Check your Content-Type in Postman. Set it to  `Content-Type : application/json`

Comment: Have you tried use attribute FromBody or something?

Comment: @SajithK ur right i missed that detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change header in postman to app json, double check your request headers